# Is it possible to auto-arrange the active Unity launcher icons?

Tags: unity, launcher

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 x64 bit as default DE.

I was guessing it is possible to Auto Arrange the Current-Active applications in Unity Launcher panel to align in Lastly-Opened or Firstly-Opened in ascending or descending order, irrespective of their locked positions in the Unity Launcher panel.

Just to get rid of Scrolling down the launcher panel every time to search active application thereby depriving the need of Alt-Tab shortcut.

I mean Alt-Tab alternative in more smarter way, though I also use Alt-Tab for the task Management purpose.

Comment: I don't think this exists. It's more of a feature request. You should totally post it in Launchpad because it's a really good idea.

Comment: Yes Felipe i think, i should post it as feature request.

Comment: Not an answer to your exact question but you can also rearrange the icons manually by dragging them 'out' and then back 'in' at a different spot (just in case you didn't know)

Comment: @ Michael Durrant- I am aware of that , i asked for the possibility of auto-arranging Feature of active windows on desktop ,rather than arranging the icons for specified Need-based-session .It will be illogical (on Unity's Design Principle) to re-arrange them for every session :)

Comment: @tijybba Did you request the feature? Are you still waiting for an answer. If not, I think this question should be closed

Comment: I did posted it in launchpad. And in brainstorm too , i was asked to join the [Ayatana Project mailing list](https://launchpad.net/ayatana) but never got the confirmation mail. So i cannot make out , what to do about this.

Comment: @tijybba. I think, you should close this question.

Comment: @tijybba The "answer" to this question would be that the feature doesn't currently exist but has (recently) been requested (by you). **;-)** I recommend that you self-answer this question, including links to both the Launchpad bug and the Brainstorm idea you filed. As for joining the Ayatana Project mailing list, if you're having trouble with that, you should *definitely* post a separate question about that--it's very unlikely that problem will be dealt with here (and it's a separate issue from the main topic of this question).

Comment: @AnwarShah & [Eliah Kagan](http://askubuntu.com/users/22949/eliah-kagan) - I Voted to close it, needs 4 more votes.

Comment: @tijybba. thanks, The problem is I can't vote to close it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question. Thanks to [Eliah Kagan](https://askubuntu.com/users/22949/eliah-kagan) and [Anwar Shah](https://askubuntu.com/users/61218/anwar-shah) for suggesting it.

From the comments i was inclined to post it as  **Feature request** , and posted it at **Ubuntu Brainstorm** under the heading

> [**Smarter way of navigating the Active application Windows in
>   UNITY**](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/29780/)

They further suggested to post it as **Unity design improvement** through

> [**The Unity design process (and how you can play a part in it)**](http://design.canonical.com/2012/02/the-unity-design-process-and-how-you-can-play-a-part-in-it/)

I did and asked in **launchpad** here under the same title

> [**Is it possible to auto-arrange the active Unity launcher
>   icons?**](https://answers.launchpad.net/unity/+question/198537)

Where i was led to subscribe [**Unity design mailing list**](https://launchpad.net/~unity-design) also known as  the **“Ayatana Discussion” team** .

Well the answer here now stands as **Requested Feature** , which means it is no longer helpful here . So i am closing it . If in future releases this gets addressed , i may vote to **Reopen** it.

> Thank you, for All the Help :)